# Repair error pop up in .xlsx file in mail in zip format in java apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I have used apache poi 3.11 to generate .xlsx files. After that we were required to zip it and send it via email.

But then we try to open the file within the email we get the

> "We found a problem with some content in 'FileName.xlsx'.Do you want
>   us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of
>   this workbook, Click Yes"

popup. and recovers our data as well. But i do not understand why  this error occurs.

We have even tried to generate this code using fileOutputStream "Temp.xlsx" this time there is no error popup. But when we write the workbook to a byteoutputstream . It gives us this error. We have even set the mimeType as "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
We have attached the code snippet plus the popup image.

Please guide us further!

For reference below is the code:

```
@Override
    public ByteArrayOutputStream createWorkBookForEmailXSSF(ExtractionRequestBean extractionRequestBeans, ByteArrayOutputStream outputstream) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        XSSFWorkbook xwb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFCellStyle headerStyle= SpreadSheetGenerator.settingHeaderStyle(xwb);
        SpreadSheetGenerator.setttingNumberStyle(xwb);
        SpreadSheetGenerator.setttingNumberDecimalStyle(xwb);
        SpreadSheetGenerator.setttingDateStyle(xwb);
        XSSFSheet sheet = xwb.createSheet(extractionRequestBeans.getFileName());
        SpreadSheetGenerator.createHeader(sheet, extractionRequestBeans.getHeaderValues(), headerStyle);
        SpreadSheetGenerator.createRows(extractionRequestBeans, sheet, xwb);
        SpreadSheetGenerator.settingAutosizeColumns(sheet, extractionRequestBeans.getHeaderValues());
        xwb.write(outputstream);
        outputstream.write(xwb.toString().getBytes());
        outputstream.close();
        return outputstream;
    }
}




public static XSSFCellStyle settingHeaderStyle(XSSFWorkbook xwb) {
        XSSFCellStyle style = xwb.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont font = xwb.createFont();
        //font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_40_PERCENT.getIndex());
        //style.setFillPattern(XSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        style.setFont(font);
        return style;
}

public static XSSFCellStyle setttingNumberStyle(XSSFWorkbook xwb) {
        XSSFCellStyle style = xwb.createCellStyle();
        DataFormat format = xwb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("0"));
        return style;
}

public static XSSFCellStyle setttingNumberDecimalStyle(XSSFWorkbook xwb) {
        XSSFCellStyle style = xwb.createCellStyle();
        DataFormat format = xwb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("0.00"));
        return style;
}

public static XSSFCellStyle setttingDateStyle(XSSFWorkbook xwb) {
        XSSFCellStyle style = xwb.createCellStyle();
        DataFormat format = xwb.createDataFormat();
        style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("m/d/yy h:mm"));
        return style;
}
public static void createHeader(XSSFSheet sheet, List<String> headerValues, XSSFCellStyle style) {
        addHeaderRow(sheet, 0, headerValues, style);
}

private static void addHeaderRow(XSSFSheet sheet, int i, List<String> headerValues, XSSFCellStyle style) {
        logger.info("Start : [SpreadSheetGenerator - createHeaderRow - Start Generating Header]");
        XSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((int) 0);
        int cellIndex = 0;
        for (String headerLabel : headerValues) {
                    addHeaderCell(rowhead, cellIndex, headerLabel, style);
                    cellIndex++;
        }
        logger.info("End : [SpreadSheetGenerator - createHeaderRow - Start Generating Header]");
}

private static void addHeaderCell(XSSFRow rowhead, int cellIndex, String headerLabel, XSSFCellStyle style) {
        if (headerLabel != null && !headerLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    rowhead.createCell(cellIndex).setCellValue(headerLabel.toString());
        } else {
                    rowhead.createCell(cellIndex).setCellValue("");
        }
        rowhead.getCell(cellIndex).setCellStyle(style);
}

public static void settingAutosizeColumns(XSSFSheet sheet, List<String> headerValues) {
        for (int autoSizeIndex = 0; autoSizeIndex < headerValues.size(); autoSizeIndex++) {
                    sheet.autoSizeColumn(autoSizeIndex);
        }
}

public static void createRows(ExtractionRequestBean extractionRequestBean, XSSFSheet sheet, XSSFWorkbook hwb) {
        logger.info("Start : [SpreadSheetGenerator - createRows - Start Generating Excel Rows ]");
        int rowIndex = 1;
        for (Object[] obj : extractionRequestBean.getDatas()) {
             addRow(sheet, rowIndex, obj, extractionRequestBean.getCellStyleMap(), hwb);
             rowIndex++;
        }
        logger.info("End : [SpreadSheetGenerator - createRows - End Generating Excel Rows]");
}

private static void addRow(XSSFSheet sheet, int rowIndex, Object[] obj, Map<Integer, Integer> cellStyleMap, XSSFWorkbook hwb) {
        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((int) rowIndex);
        int cellIndex = 0;
        addCell(obj, row, cellIndex, cellStyleMap, hwb);
}

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static void addCell(Object[] obj, XSSFRow row, int cellIndex, Map<Integer, Integer> cellStyleMap, XSSFWorkbook hwb) {
        for (Object object : obj) {
            if (cellStyleMap.get(cellIndex) == HSSFCellStyleEnum.ONLYSTRING.getStyleCode()) {
                row.createCell(cellIndex).setCellValue(object != null ? object.toString() : "");
            } else if (cellStyleMap.get(cellIndex) == HSSFCellStyleEnum.NUMERICWITHDECIMAL.getStyleCode()) {
                row.createCell(cellIndex).setCellValue(object != null ? Double.valueOf(object.toString()) : 0d);
            } else if (cellStyleMap.get(cellIndex) == HSSFCellStyleEnum.NUMERICWITHOUTDECIMAL.getStyleCode()) {
                row.createCell(cellIndex).setCellValue(object != null ? Double.valueOf(object.toString()) : 0d);
            } else if (cellStyleMap.get(cellIndex) == HSSFCellStyleEnum.ONLYDATE.getStyleCode()) {
                row.createCell(cellIndex).setCellValue(object != null ? DateUtil.formatDateOnly(new Date(object.toString()))  : "");
            }
            cellIndex++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Apache POI 3.11 is a little old, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: 1. Why posting an image of the code instead of the code? 2. After `hwb.write(fileOut)` the `hwb` cannot be used further because final commits where made before writing (saving the `OPCPackage`). 3. Where is `outputStream` coming from in your code? 4. What are the intentions behind the writing `outputStream.write(hwb.toString().getBytes())` after `hwb.write(outputStream)`?

Comment: @Gagravarr -facing the same issue after upgrade the version also

Comment: @Axel Richter-We are sending the byteoutputstream object from  method-below is the code 
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
spreadsheetWork.createWorkBookForEmailXSSF(bean, outputStream);

Comment: The `outputstream.write(xwb.toString().getBytes());` is wrong to build an `*.xlsx` stream. Please check what `xwb.toString()` returns. Is it what you are expecting? A `*.xlsx` is a `ZIP` archive containing **multiple** files in directories. The `xwb.write(outputstream);` does writing this already to the stream. So remove the `outputstream.write(xwb.toString().getBytes());` and do `outputstream.flush();` instead of `close()`. Closing a ByteArrayOutputStream has no effect.

Comment: @Alex Richter-Thanks for your suggestion, it works wonderfully.Thank you so much for your help.